# How is deviated nasal septum related to cold

Tags: human-biology

I have a deviated  nasal septum and I always suffer from  common cold I was just wondering how a deviated nasal septum can be the cause for chronic common cold

Comment: Question: What makes you think it's the deviated septum instead of different cold strains?

Comment: I am not sure but I was told by a doctor that I have deviated nasal septum and he suggested for and operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nasal septum deviation is a condition where the cartilage which divides the nasal cavity into two nasal passages isn't centrally aligned, making one of the nostrils smaller and thus obstructed. Now, in our nose we have something called [mucociliary clearance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucociliary_clearance) and that is the mechanism getting rid of unwanted particles and pathogens that get into contact with the mucous membranes in the nose.

Studies show that in individuals with a deviated septum the [nasal mucociliary clearance time is slower than in individuals whose nasal passages are symmetrical](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19816701). From this information one can conclude that the particles and pathogens that you inhale are getting to spend more time inside your nasal passages, thus giving the pathogens a better chance at striving and giving you sinusitis.

By looking at the information above you could think that the connection between nasal septum deviation and chronic sinusitis is clear. [This literary review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11859650) however states that the correlation between a deviated nasal septum and having chronic sinusitis is still unclear.